# QuickBooks NULL CallbackHandler

Tags: java, quickbooks

I'm trying to perform a batch operation in QuickBook but getting null callbackhandler.

```
private static void AddBulkCustomer(DataService ds) throws FMSException{

        BatchOperation bo = new BatchOperation();
        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        c1.setGivenName("Customer 3");
        c1.setDisplayName("Disp Customer 3");
        EmailAddress email = new EmailAddress();
        email.setAddress("customer1@zzz.com");
        c1.setPrimaryEmailAddr(email);

        bo.addEntity(c1, OperationEnum.CREATE, "b3");

        c1= null;
        c1 = new Customer();
        c1.setGivenName("Customer 4");
        c1.setDisplayName("Disp Customer 4");
        email = null;
        email = new EmailAddress();
        email.setAddress("customer2@z2zz.com");
        c1.setPrimaryEmailAddr(email);

        bo.addEntity(c1, OperationEnum.CREATE, "b4");

//      String strQuery = " select * from customer where givenname ='"+c1.getGivenName()+"'";
//      bo.addQuery(strQuery, "b3Query");

        ds.executeBatchAsync(bo, new AsyncCallBackBatch());
    }
```

For AsyncCallback operation

```
public class AsyncCallBackBatch implements CallbackHandler {


    @Override
    public void execute(CallbackMessage callbackMsg) {
        System.out.println("asyncCallbackBatch is executing... ");
        try {
                System.out.println("QR = "+callbackMsg.getFMSException().toString());
                BatchOperation BO = callbackMsg.getBatchOperation();
                if (BO != null) {
                List<String> bId = BO.getBIds();
                for (String strBId : bId) {
                    if (BO.isFault(strBId)) {
                        Fault fault = BO.getFault(strBId);
                        System.out.println("asyncCallBackBatch Error Code : "+ fault.getError().get(0).getCode() + " "+ "Error : "
                                + fault.getError().get(0).getDetail()+ ", Message : "+ fault.getError().get(0).getMessage());
                    } else if (BO.isEntity(strBId)) {
                        System.out.println("Batch having entity message.. ");
                        Customer cust = (Customer) BO.getEntity(strBId);
                        System.out.println("cust id : " + cust.getId()+ " CustName = " + cust.getGivenName());
                    } else if (BO.isQuery(strBId)) {
                        System.out.println("Batch having Query ... Parsing...  ");
                        QueryResult qR = BO.getQueryResponse(strBId);
                        System.out.println("Query : " + qR.getTotalCount());
                    } else if (BO.isReport(strBId)) {
                        System.out.println("Batch having Report...  ");
                        Report report = BO.getReport(strBId);
                        System.out.println(" " + report.getClass().getName());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Something went wrong... ");
                    }
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Batch Operation terminated, reason: NULL callbackMsg ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        OAuthAuthorizer oAuth = new OAuthAuthorizer(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

        //403352746

        try {

            Context context = new Context(oAuth, ServiceType.QBO, "403352746");
            System.out.println("RealmID : "+context.getRealmID());
            context.setCustomerRequestTimeout(99999);
            System.out.println("TimeOut Set to = "+context.getCustomerRequestTimeout());

            System.out.println("BASE_URL_QBO = "+Config.getProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO));
            Config.setProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO, "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company");
            System.out.println("BASE_URL_QBO = "+Config.getProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO));
            DataService ds = new DataService(context);

            AddBulkCustomer(ds);
            System.out.println("Operation Complete..");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

When I debug, in execute method, I'm getting Null BatchOperation in return. I'm not sure performing Batch operation is allowed in sandbox environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after so much of testing and communication with Quickbooks Devs thought would be helpful for others.

In sandbox environment even if you set the config properties to sandbox URL it still picks as PROD URL in Callbackhandler.

```
    Config.setProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO, "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company");
```

In this case they called this as a bug, currently all you can do is to make a trial account in PROD and then test this.